# Bind Business Object to ASP.NET DataList

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, data-binding, reflection

I have a business object with a `Dictionary<string, Contact>` field that I would like to bind to a ASP.NET `DataList` using reflection.  The `ItemTemplate` for the `DataList` defines four `TextBox` controls.  Three of these have the same `ID` as properties of the current `Contact` object from the `Dictionary<string, Contact>`.  The fourth `TextBox` should be bound to the `string` key.

I have already written code that strips out the individual `Contact` objects, the key field, the `DataList` control and the name of the property/template controls to be bound.  The trouble I am having is specifying the values for each control.

I have a method with the following signature:

```
private void AssignControlValue(Contact contact, PropertyInfo pi, DataList control, string key = "")
{

}
```

What do I need to do to tie this all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to bind the business objects to the DataList. In this case, I think you would want to bind to the `ValueCollection` of the dictionary:

```
DataList1.DataSource = dict.Values;
```

After doing this, you should be able to use normal databinding syntax:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("SomeProperty") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

If you're looking for another option, you can probably use an `ObjectDataSource` control too. Check out the link below for more details.

[Binding DataList to ObjectDataSource](http://www.dotnetcodecentral.com/Post/115/asp-net-databinding-objectdatasource/binding-datalist-to-objectdatasource-control)

Comment: I was able to get the values collection to do the trick.  Sometimes you stare at something long enough even the most obvious things just stop making sense.  Thanks!